# When setting up Stripe Webhook Signing, should we reject unsigned events?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm setting up Stripe subscription payments by following [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout).

In step 4 (provision and monitor subscriptions) Stripe tells us to set up a Webhook to process subscription events.

When a webhook event is received its signature can be authenticated to ensure it was sent by Stripe and not a malicious third party.

But in their code example immediately after authenticating the signature, they include an `else` block to retrieve event data directly from the request body for non-signed events.

I'm confused why they have included that. Shouldn't it be one or the other instead of allowing both?

My understanding is that having both negates the point of webhook authentication because now signed AND non-signed events are allowed.

If I have webhook signing set up, should I remove that `else` block?

You can see the example code below at lines 28-33.

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('API_KEY_GOES_HERE');

app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
  let data;
  let eventType;
  // Check if webhook signing is configured.
  const webhookSecret = {{'STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET'}}
  if (webhookSecret) {
    // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
    let event;
    let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        req.body,
        signature,
        webhookSecret
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
      return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    // Extract the object from the event.
    data = event.data;
    eventType = event.type;
  } else {
    // Webhook signing is recommended, but if the secret is not configured in `config.js`,
    // retrieve the event data directly from the request body.
    data = req.body.data;
    eventType = req.body.type;
  }

  switch (eventType) {
      case 'checkout.session.completed':
        // Payment is successful and the subscription is created.
        // You should provision the subscription and save the customer ID to your database.
        break;
      case 'invoice.paid':
        // Continue to provision the subscription as payments continue to be made.
        // Store the status in your database and check when a user accesses your service.
        // This approach helps you avoid hitting rate limits.
        break;
      case 'invoice.payment_failed':
        // The payment failed or the customer does not have a valid payment method.
        // The subscription becomes past_due. Notify your customer and send them to the
        // customer portal to update their payment information.
        break;
      default:
      // Unhandled event type
    }

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: If you don't have any webhook secret configured your data will de retrieved,  you are verifying the signature server side, using the secret key so unsigned events can be passed, but it is safe to have a signed event because any bad actor can send a request like manipulating an order

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar so you're saying I should keep both? In that case, checking the signature seems pointless because I am also passing through events that are not signed.

Comment: It is recommended to have a signed webhook event, stripe uses your private key to sign and later can be verified by you on the server-side, it is recommended that you have all the webhooks signed. so any unsigned signatures are from bad actors and you can use the else clasue to keep the logs for security purposer

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar that's what I thought. So why does the Stripe code example allow for both? That is the question I am asking. I am not asking what is webhook signing or why it is needed. I am asking why their code example allows for both signed and non-signed events.

Comment: good question, there are some events which are important like the paid and some events which are less important and doesn't matter and is only used for logging purpose and some users don't wants to verify the signature, so stripe allows for both, it is best that every events are signed.

Comment: There's a comment included in the code you've pasted which explains exactly why it is there ... :-)  Using signatures is optional; if you haven't set it up yet, or have chosen not to use it, they are showing you how to retrieve the webhook data.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The code and the comment makes it sound like both signed and unsigned code blocks should be left in place. If they only expected us to have one or another it wouldn't be coded as an if/else block. The comment tries to explain why it's there (to allow unsigned webhooks) but it makes no sense to have both at the same time, thus why I'm asking the question. I get that sigs are optional, but allowing both in the code seems strange.

Comment: It does not sound like that to me at all.  "*... but if the secret is not configured ...*" - means the first block is entirely unnecessary, this is clearly an either/or example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Stripe directly and they have advised that "it should be one or another, not both."

So if you have Webhook signing setup then you should take the signature authentication out of the `if/else` block, thus making the `if/else` useless, so remove that also.

Here is the updated version:

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('API_KEY_GOES_HERE');

app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {

  // Check if webhook signing is configured.
  const webhookSecret = {{'STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET'}}

  // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
  let event;
  let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      req.body,
      signature,
      webhookSecret
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  }
  // Extract the object from the event.
  let data = event.data;
  let eventType = event.type;

  switch (eventType) {
      case 'checkout.session.completed':
        // Payment is successful and the subscription is created.
        // You should provision the subscription and save the customer ID to your database.
        break;
      case 'invoice.paid':
        // Continue to provision the subscription as payments continue to be made.
        // Store the status in your database and check when a user accesses your service.
        // This approach helps you avoid hitting rate limits.
        break;
      case 'invoice.payment_failed':
        // The payment failed or the customer does not have a valid payment method.
        // The subscription becomes past_due. Notify your customer and send them to the
        // customer portal to update their payment information.
        break;
      default:
      // Unhandled event type
    }

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```